# WMQ C++ Get request's message id and set it correlation id for reply

Tags: c++, ibm-mq

I have a problem on getting message id and set it on reply's correlation id.

Here's the piece of code:

```
MQBYTE msgID;

request_msg.messageId().copyOut(msgID, MQ_MSG_ID_LENGTH, 0);
response_msg.setCorrelationId(msgID);
```

when I checked the correlation Id of the reply, the correlation id is 0.

How can I copy/get the messageId of the request and put it on the correlation id of the reply?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: MessageId is a 24 byte long array. But your code is using just 1 byte, `MQBYTE msgID;` Did your code compile or is a typo while posting code here? 

I am using MQ v8002 and code above works fine.

Comment: yes, it compiles. but the result results on 0000000000000

Comment: yes, it compiles. but the result is series of 0s. How can I get and pass the msgId to corelid? I just want to correlate the request and reply to each other so that I can track them using msgId/correlId.

Answer (score 4):

The Infocenter page [*Manipulating binary strings in C++*](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/uc10520_.htm?lang=en) shows the data types involved as `ImqBinary` and `MQBYTE24`.  As Shashi notes in the comments, `MQBYTE` is a single byte and incapable of containing a 24-byte message ID.  The page linked above provides a reference example:

```
#include <imqi.hpp> // C++ classes

ImqMessage message ;
ImqBinary id, correlationId ;
MQBYTE24 byteId ;

correlationId.set( byteId, sizeof( byteId ) ); // Set.
id = message.id( );                            // Assign.
if ( correlationId == id ) {                   // Compare.
  ...
```

One tool to diagnose issues like this is the very useful [SupportPac MA0W](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMA0W) which is an API exit.  It can show you the exact contents of the structures passed to MQ before and after an API call.  Very often what is seen is that what is expected (in this case having copied the `MQMD.MsgID` to the `MQMD.CorrelID` is not what actually happened.  In this case, I believe a trace such as that provided by MA0W would reveal that the `msgID` was accurately passed from the app to MQ but consisted of only one character.

**UPDATE**
OP asks:

> Variable `id` is an `ImqBinary` and `message` is an `ImqMessage`
>   object, from what I know `id` is not a member of `ImqMessage` like
>   `messageId`, `correlationId`, `groupId` and etc. so how can
>   `message.id()` passed it's value on `id`?

You are coorrect that `id` is a declared variable of type `ImqBinary` and not a member of the `ImqMessage` class.  Please see the Infocenter page for the [*ImqBinary C++ class*](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/uc10640_.htm?lang=en) which explains that:

> This class encapsulates a binary byte array that can be used for
>   ImqMessage accounting token, correlation id, and message id values. It
>   allows easy assignment, copying, and comparison.

The intent of the `ImqBinary` class is to provide a variable type to encapsulate a byte array with overloaded methods such that "normal" variable manipulations work as expected.  Rather than copying the byte array one byte at a time, it can be an `LVAL` or `RVAL` in an assignment.  Rather than comparing the array a byte at a time, you can just use comparison operators like `==`.

So if your code were modified to use the example, it might look like this:

```
#include <imqi.hpp> // C++ classes

ImqMessage request_msg, response_msg ;
ImqBinary id ;

id = request_msg.id( );
response_msg.setCorrelationId(id);
```

That said, I'm not sure you even need an intermediate variable.  You might be able to assign the correlation ID using the output of the getter call for the message ID from the source message.  Something like....

```
response_msg.setCorrelationId( request_msg.id( ) );
```

...might do it.  I don't code C or C++ anymore so I probably got the syntax wrong or didn't do it as elegantly as it might be coded, but you should get the idea.

Comment: I will take a look at it and will let you know. I have a question regarding with this code snippet.

id = message.id( );                            // Assign.

variable id is an ImqBinary and message is an ImqMessage object, from what I know id is not a member of ImqMessage like messageId, correlationId, groupId and etc.

so how can message.id() passed it's value on id?

sorry I'm just confused on how this works.

Comment: Hi Rob. Thanks for the idea. I tried response_msg.setCorrelationId(request_msg.correlationid( ) ); and it compiles but when I checked on the Queue. I has a result of 0s. However, I tried another approach and combined with your idea.

ImqBinary buffer;

I used the request_msg.copyOut(buffer,MQ_MSG_ID_LENGTH,0) then set the correlation id like this, response_msg.setCorrelationId(buffer,24) and it works like a charm